# "mysql_select_db" fails while "mysql_connect" OK

Tags: php, mysql-connect, mysql-select-db

new here, only starting basic PHP. Trying to understand the specifics of the two MySQL commands.
Please see this code

```
<?php   
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password= "";
$databaseName = "alphacrm";

$dbConnected = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

$dbSelected = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $dbConnected);   ?>
```

If I run the code:

`mysql_connect` - successful

`mysql_select_db` - failed.

Question:
why won't both fail if the `$username` is empty/wrong?

Note: I know I just need to input the value for `$username` and it will work. I am not trying to make it work, I am trying to understand why BOTH functions are not failing when `$username` has no value

## Thanks.

Edit:
@Jason: Thank you, I now know I am using outdated learning material

Comment: Make sure the database exists and the user can access it.

Comment: Have you tried viewing database with phpmyadmin?

Comment: FYI: mysql* has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5 (http://us2.php.net/mysql_connect)  Do yourself (and your project) a favor and make the transition to mysqli* (http://us2.php.net/mysqli) now.

Comment: Begs the question: Are you are using php5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get more information with

```
if ($dbSelected){
 ...
} else {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

it might tell you what the problem is!

Put it in both of your `else` statements so you will know what mysql is doing!

Comment: Only 2nd day with PHP, not pretending to know better, but a lot of sources are against "die" method, e.g.:http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die

Comment: Tried. Says:`DB connection FAILEDCan't use foo : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'alphacrm'` Understandable, I left `$username` undefined. BUT it still connects to MySql with that `$username` as a parameter. So does `mysql_connect` ignore invalid parameters by default/nature?

Comment: $username is '' so it is an empty String actually in your case a single space " ", it is not undefined! Take out $username entirely!

Comment: It tries to connect do the db with a username of " " but the authentication fails!

Comment: Andrey the die method is taken directly from the documentation example of mysql_connect!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect` is enclosed in a variable `$dbConnected`, it is nothing to do until unless it has been put in `mysql_connect`.

when PHP reads the `mysql_connect` it finds the incorrect `credentials` so that's wht `mysql_connect` fails.

Comment: `mysql_connect` is actually successful, it is `mysql_select_db` that fails. the `credential`, in this case the `$username` is wrong (I made it intentionally), so I expected both functions to fail. But only `mysql_select_db` failed. And I wondered why?

Comment: I just tested just these functions. For me, already connect fails when credentials are wrong. So that it doesn't fail for you, I find indeed strange.